# Magento 2: Get custom attribute in catalog category view page

Tags: magento2

I created a custom attribute for hiding add to cart button. I want to get attribute in the list.phtml file.

Answer (score 1):

We can get custom attribute Label & Value like below:

**Attribute Value**

```
<?php /* @escapeNotVerified */ echo $_product->getResource()->getAttribute('your_attribute_name')->getFrontend()->getValue($_product); ?>
```

**Label**

```
$address =$_product->getResource()->getAttribute('your_attribute_name')->getStoreLabel();
```

**I hope it will help..!!**

Comment: I have already use this code but error generated....Uncaught Error: Call to a member function getResource() on null in view/frontend/templates/product/list.phtml

Comment: @kiya: can you add that error here?

Comment: Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Call to a member function getResource() on null in /var/www/html/magento2.3/app/code/Vendor/Mymodule/view/frontend/templates/product/list.phtml

Comment: @kiya : can you add your list.phtml file's code here?

Comment: @kiya: Make sure “Visible on Product View Page on Front-end” and “Used in Product Listing” options under storefront Properties are set to Yes. Can you verify above settings for your custom attribute once?

Comment: already properties set to yes...

Comment: @kiya : can you add your list.phtml file's code here?

Comment: +1 for ensuring "Used in Product Listing" is set to yes. Was pulling out my hair for hours trying to figure out why my attribute wasn't available. On a side note, you can use `$_product->getData(your_attribute)` to get the value and `$_product->getAttributeText(your_attribute)` to get the label value if your looking for something a bit shorter.